# How to get wordpress login authentication details

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, authentication

Hi I want to create a wordpress connect for our codeigniter site , and connect our own wordpress site.I was create a login page and done all wordpress authentication successfully.But  I need

```
`If I am already logged into Wordpress and then go to the codeigniter site ,  I should see the "Welcome Admin" in the upper right to indicate that I am logged in`.
```

But I cant take the authentication details from wordpress site.is it possible to get login details from wordpress ?Any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Single Sign On solution. Signing into either of the sites will allow you to be signed into the other.

To accomplish this, you might have to re-organize how people log in. You have 2 options:

1) The more secure way would be to have ONE source for logins. Then, implement an oAuth type solution so that if a person visits the other source and tries to login, they are redirected to the main source...login...and then they are sent back to where they originally tried to login.  I've done this a couple times with the oAuth plugin for wordpress and writing custom code in my other site (which was CakePHP...but it shouldn't matter).

2) Another way would be to write a custom plugin that when a person logs in with codeigniter, they are manually logged in in the background to wordpress. Not nearly as secure...but if your site doesn't have a need for decent security it might be an option.  Here your issue is that you won't know the WP password in order to do proper authentication.